# iOS - switch audio output from Phone, Phone Speaker, earphones or Bluetooth device

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth, avaudiosession

I'm working on a project about video&audio chat. Audio output has many type, just as Apple list in develop document:

```
/* output port types */
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortLineOut;
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones;
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInReceiver;
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP;
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker;
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortHDMI;
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay;
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothLE;

/* port types that refer to either input or output */
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP;
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortUSBAudio;
NSString *const AVAudioSessionPortCarAudio;
```

If now I find three audio output types:iPhone Speaker, iPhone inner speaker and Bluetooth device, how to switch output each other?

I use the code below to change audio output from bluetooth device to speaker. And it works:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
```

I use this code below to change audio from other type to bluetooth, it also works:

```
NSArray *availInputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
int count = [availInputs count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    AVAudioSessionPortDescription* inPort = [availInputs objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([self isBluetoothDevice:inPort.portType])
    {
         NSError *setPreferredErr = nil;
         [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:inPort error:&setPreferredErr];
         if(setPreferredErr)
              NSLog (@"%@", setPreferredErr);
     }
}
```

But I can't change output from bluetooth to iPhone inner speaker.
  How about change from bluetooth to earphones?
  Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to switch between build-in speaker and the speaker(the one that is near to front camera)?

Comment: Did you find solution for this..i am also facing same issue?

Comment: @IosDeveloper I used MPVolumeView to implement this. System will do this for us.